# Avoid UIBarButtonItem fade out / fade in during pushViewController animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have in my only-ios5 application a navigationControllerDelegate:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIBarButtonItem *myButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"common-settingsbutton"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    [viewController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:myButton]; 
}
```

It works, but when a push view controller with default animation occurs (i.e. using a "push segue") the rightBarButtonItem fadeout and fadein during animation.

How can I avoid this?

---

**UPDATE**

The only *workaround* I found is:
create **UINavigationBar background** with same UIBarButtonItems drawn in png (in the same position, same color) and set background correctly based on buttons I need. 
Then, of course, add your UIBarButtonItems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only workaround I found is:
create UINavigationBar background with same UIBarButtonItems drawn in png (in the same position, same color) and set background correctly based on buttons I need. Then, of course, add your UIBarButtonItems.

Answer (score 0):

Create button before pushing in the view controller instead of in protocol method.

Comment: I got the same behavior, and also I will need to implement the same code in all "prepareForSegue" in each viewcontroller instead of having code in just one place

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs you can disable the animation for a BarButtonItem

```
[viewController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:myButton animated:NO];
```

But this does not seem to work in a storyboarded project. The button still animates in.

Answer (score 0):

```
button. adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
```

When u click on rightBarButton its highlighted like Fade In/ Fade Out. To avoid that one property of that button adjustsImageWhenHighlighted is set to NO.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: Feel free to paste this into the answer. Thank you !